# Class correlation and its effects

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, correlation

I was going through the iris dataset here : https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/ and I found this:

```
 Summary Statistics:
 Min  Max   Mean    SD   Class Correlation
sepal length: 4.3  7.9   5.84  0.83    0.7826   
sepal width: 2.0  4.4   3.05  0.43   -0.4194
petal length: 1.0  6.9   3.76  1.76    0.9490  (high!)
petal width: 0.1  2.5   1.20  0.76    0.9565  (high!)
```

What does class correlation signify and what can one infer from it being high or low for a particular feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class Correlation is [Pearson's Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between a Class (a.k.a Target Variable or Response) and other Features (a.k.a Independent Variables).

Pearson's Correlation Coefficient *Absolute* Value ranges between 0 to 1 (1 means perfect relation).

For example, in your Iris dataset, there are **3 Classes** (i.e. Species of Iris), namely: *Setosa, Versicolour and Virginica*.

On the other hand, you have **4 Features**, namely:  *sepal length, sepal width, petal length and petal width*.

It's good to find the correlation between a class from above, and one of the features in the dataset, ...Why? To see how much that feature/attribute worth to the class. In other words, the reliability of the class on that attribute.

---

From your dataset for example, **petal width** has the highest correlation with the classes (`corr=0.9565`), that means: the changes in petal widths highly cause changes in the classes linearly!

So as a result, the feature **petal width** is very important to model the dataset as well as to predict any future unseen new example!

The same for **petal length** which has very high correlation with other classes.

---

As a rule of thumb, Pearson's Correlation Absolute Value can be interpreted as the follows:

- Weak: from 0.1 to 0.29
- Intermediate: from 0.3 to 0.49
- Strong: 0.5 to 1

and that's according to Cohen's Standard.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter seems to describe [Intraclass correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation), which is a measure of similarity within a class or group.

A higher value indicates that samples from that class tend to be similar, while a lower value indicates the opposite.

Comment: So does that make that class less important because of the similarity?

Comment: Not less important, but more consistent. It might be an indicator for easier classification, but take that with a grain of salt.